# is there a way to take angular 6 libraries to angularJS applications without migrate the code-base into ES6 or ES5

Tags: angularjs, angular, image-editor

I am working on a big CMS project which is developed by angularJS and suddenly I have to change the image cropping tool to a new image editing tool. since there are no anguarJS based project which full fill my requirements and There are some projects that can possibly usable but which written using angular2 or higher version, I am looking for a way to integrate some of those libraries to my angularJS code-base somehow. It may be a really stupid question, but I am out of options here. Any advises would be really helpful.

As a example, what if I want to add this image editor which is developed for angular 2 [Angular 2 Photo Editor SDK for HTML5.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-photo-editor) in to my angularJS project – Sanira 1 min ago
Actually it has to "order for licence", But I just asking is there a way to integrate that kind of angular 2 component in to an angularJS project

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.
As a example, what if I want to add this image editor which is developed for angular 2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-photo-editor in to my angularJS project